# SAS Comparison operator evaluating incorrectly

Tags: sas

I am translating codes from SAS to R and use PivotalR package to run SQL(POSTGRESQL) statements from R.

While translating, I observed that in SAS, some records do not get selected even if they meet the conditions specified in the where clause in PROC SQL statements.

```
PROC SQL;
Create table name as select .....
.........from table1 as t1
where t1.re <=10 and t1.se >= 20;
QUIT;
```

Some records that make the cut, get selected while some simply do not, especially when the column values are equal to the limit(in the above case re=10 and se=20).

I do not face this problem when I run the equivalent query from R. Is there any logical explanation for this?(Running POSTRESQL on GREEN PLUM )

Comment: Is t1.re/t1.se a whole number or decimal number? You might be running into floating point errors, i.e. the number is actually stored as 10.00001. Try using a Explicit SQL pass through?

Comment: I'd advise trying to see if you're getting the same problem in a data step - doesn't sound like you know sas at all, but it should be a relatively simple exercise to convert just the where clause into a data step.

Comment: @undershock Actually, data step `where` clause works identically to SQL (it allows some SQL syntax, in fact).  You can conver to an `if`, but I don't think that would be functionally different as it likely would be converted to SQL by SAS anyway - SAS would try to pass this back to Greenplum.

Comment: @Reeza You were right. Rounding error in Postgresql. SAS is not displaying the value with the precision with which it is stored but, evaluates the condition correctly. Unfortunately Postgesql rounds the precision and hence the anomaly. Now i know what my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Reeza says, it is possible that there is some problem with exact integer values when imported from postgres.

You can use pass through to have the database do the processing rather than SAS. This should allow you to get the result you expect from the where clause as the PostgreSQL will be doing the work.

```
proc sql;
    /* Open database connection */
    connect to postgres as pg (/* Connection options, same as in libname */);

    /* Create a SAS dataset */
    create table name as
    select * 
    from connection to pg (
        /* Postgres SQL statement to be run on the Postgres server */
        select *
        from table1 as t1
        where 
            t1.re <=10 and 
            t1.se >= 20
    );
    /* Close database connection */
    disconnect from pg;
quit;
```

If this gives the same unexpected result then it is likely that the behaviour you are seeing in R is anomalous, if not then you now have the data you want in SAS.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the limit to accommodate possible rounding error.(changed limit 25.00 to 24.95) I was able to see the difference in R(pass-through) and SAS. I verified this by using simple data step for a small dataset in SAS.